# Limitar acceso a url publica desde un dominio especifico

Tags: laravel, http, url

Desarrolle un formulario en Laravel de acceso publico(no tiene ningún tipo de autentificación para llegar a el) a través de una ruta GET. Digamos que tenemos este dominio:

**miDominio.com/formulario/miformulario** (el sitio que yo controlo), si copias y pegas esa url desde un navegador podrás acceder al formulario y llenarlo sin problema. Pero ahora estoy buscando la forma de que solo se pueda acceder a ese formulario si este es accedido desde un segundo dominio(o sitio que no controlo) supongo que para que este segundo sitio pueda acceder a mi formulario lo hará a través de una etiqueta .

Por las reglas de negocio no puedo generar autentificación para acceder a el, solo limitar el acceso a aquellas solicitudes que provengan del sitio que no controlo mencionado anteriormente. Había pensado en pedir que agregaran un header a la solicitud y verificar en mi controlador si en la request ese header existía y así permitir o no el acceso al form, pero suponiendo que la redireccion se realice a través de la etiqueta  creo no es posible agregar ese header.

Como podría limitar el acceso a mi form para se logre acceder solo desde el sitio externo?. Espero haberme hecho entender

Comment: se me ocurre que obtengas la URL anterior en el navegador, y verifiques si esa URL viene del dominio que quieres, pero más no se me ocurre jajaja

Comment: haz un middleware e interceptas el dominio, si es valido renderizas si no devuelves un 403

Comment: Laravel maneja eso utilizando CORS, deberías investigar al respecto e implementarlo en su proyecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Los navegadores agregar un header llamado referer a las solicitudes para identificar desde donde provino la solicitud respecto al sitio actual. Con esto en mente logre obtener en mi controlador cual era el sitio desde donde había partido la solicitud:

```
$referer = parse_url($request->header('referer'), PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Esto al final me regreso el dominio desde donde se hizo la solicitud, si la solicitud se realiza al mismo recurso local los navegadores no agregan este header

Mas información en [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)